Dat file not apply to an older version of my production database
I have a docker compose file like this, it will create 2 containerized app tsm and redis, the tsm app will link with redis, the database script will apply update to the database.
services:
  tsm:
    image: app-docker-image
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "80:443"
    links:
      - "tsmredis:redis"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_NAME=db name
      - DATABASE_SERVER=db server
      - DATABASE_USER=sa
      - DATABASE_PASS=sa password
      - DATABASE_SCRIPT=db_Script.dat
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - C:/Users/myuser/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
  tsmredis:
    image: redis

It work normally on the developer environment since the database of the dev was constantly updated to a newer version after code update. However the Production database which was minus 4 version  compare to the Dev database could not update to the latest version using the db_Script.dat file.
Is it an error due to the version gap or because the database deny the update from dat file?
The both database was generate using the same script.
Edit: I have recheck the log and the dat file did apply to the database but I don't know if it effect the whole database. I cannot access the database since I do not have the permission.
